# Joining a small dataset against a big dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am writing a Spark application that will run hourly. Every hour I take some ~small amount of incremental data and process it. However, I need a column to say if the row's ID is in a very large dataset.

A naive implementation would look like:

```
val output = incrementalData
  .keyBy(r => r.id)
  .leftOuterPairJoin(bigTable.keyBy(r => r.id))
  .values
  .map {
   case (row, entry) => r.copy(has_entry = entry.isDefined)
  }
```

To leverage a broadcast join, I did something different

```
val idsInLargeDataset = bigTable
  .keyBy(r => r.id)
  .pairJoin(incrementalData.hint('broadcast').keyBy(r => r.id))
  .values
  .map { case (_, flow) => flow.id }
  .distinct()

val output = incrementalData
  .keyBy(r =\> r.id)
  .leftOuterPairJoin(idsInLargeDataset)
  .values
  .map {
    case (row, entry) =\> r.copy(has_entry = entry.isDefined)
  }
```

This seems to have mostly worked! But I noticed the garbage collection time is huge (~75% of the run time of the application). Is there an obvious thing that would cause that?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you tell us what data type `bigTable` and `incrementalData` are? Also, which version of Spark are you on? I've never seen the `leftOuterPairJoin` method and googling that gives me 1 result and 1 result only: this SO post. Are there possibly typos in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the DataSet/DataFrame API. You are using regular Scala transformations and you cannot leverage Spark's full potential. When you use the DataSet or DataFrame API, it will most likely come up with a good execution plan and perform much faster.

Import col:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col}
```

Read the data using

```
val bigTable = spark.read...
val incrementalData = spark.read...
```

And then join the data like this:

```
val output = bigTable.alias("b")
  .join(incrementalData.alias("i"), $"b.id" == $"i.id", "left")
  .withColumn("isDefined", col("i.id").isNotNull)
```

Please note that the code I wrote might not work, there probably is a small syntax error. If you have any issues correcting that, let me know